# Django - asgi - uvicorn - multithreading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, uvicorn, asgi

I was trying to find out benefits and shortcomings of using asgi instead of wsgi server with async and sync view when i found that asgi was creating multiple threads for multiple requests.

I set up a demo project with 2 views (1 synchronous and 1 asynchronous with time.sleep and asyncio.sleep respectively). Using asgi  when i  make 500 simultaneous requests for synchronous view it make 500 threads (one for each request which is kind of counter intuitive because i was expecting a single thread to resolve 500 requests 1 by one), and when i make 500 simultaneous request for async view it is still creating 500 threads although when i log the thread id in async view, all requests are being handled by a single thread. I am not using any middleware or extra app that may have any synchronous code to cause this issue.
More over i tried uvicorn with FASTapi and it worked as expected (a single thread for async code).

the async view:

```
async def view(_):

await asyncio.sleep(5)
return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

Comment: It's pretty expected that the sync version will handle requests in threads (the server is supposed to be able to serve multiple clients "at the same time"). If you share the code for your async asgi demo it will be easier to tell why there are also that many threads created.

Comment: @eagr i have added the view